# How to get the security question answer

Tags: community, login, login-errors

I have forgot the my login password and security question answer of my SFDC developer account.
In my account so many components are I have configured.
How to get the new password and security question.
I have problem last 2 to 3 days.

**Some one please help me how to get the new password and my security question answer?**

[image]

Comment: You should contact Salesforce for this.